# style.top и style.left работуют лишь один раз

Tags: javascript, css, события, style, key

У меня есть проблема с JS, а точнее с использованиями стилями при помощи JS.
При нажатии на KeyD или на KeyS, элемент двигается в том направлении, куда и нужно, но когда нажимаю во второй раз (не обновляя страницу), они перестают двигаться и при этом, console.log пишем что они вошли в if, но местоположение больше не менялось, а KeyA и KeyW вообще не работали с минусовым значением. От чего зависит это всего?

```js
function onMove(event) {
    const coordsPlayer = document.getElementById('player');
    console.log(coordsPlayer.style.top);
    console.log(coordsPlayer.style.left);
    if (event.code === "KeyW") {
        console.log(coordsPlayer.style.top);
        coordsPlayer.style.top -= '25px';
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyD') {
        console.log(coordsPlayer.style.left);
        coordsPlayer.style.left += '25px';
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyA') {
        console.log(coordsPlayer.style.left);
        coordsPlayer.style.left -= '25px';
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyS') {
        console.log(coordsPlayer.style.top);
        coordsPlayer.style.top += '25px';
    } else {
        console.log('why is it not working?');
    }
}
addEventListener('keydown', onMove);
```

Буду крайне благодарен, те кто ответят на мои вопросы!
(Условии === и == не меняет ситуацию)
Можно конечно с помощью парсинга, но я не профессионал с парсингом

Comment: Как вы думаете, чему будет равно такое выражение: `'25px' + '25px'`? Или может такое: `'25px' - '25px'`?

Comment: Если я отвечу в первом '50px' или во втором '0px',  то это будет неправильно

Comment: Верно, вы делаете конкатенацию СТРОК, а не чисел. `'25px' + '25px' == '25px25px'`, а `'25px' - '25px' == NaN` т.к. у строк нельзя "отнять" строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как нужно было делать сделать:

```js
let top = 0;
let left = 0;

function onMove(event) {
    const coordsPlayer = document.getElementById('player');

    console.log(coordsPlayer.style.top);
    console.log(coordsPlayer.style.left);

    if (event.code === "KeyW") {
        top -= 25;
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyD') {
        left += 25;
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyA') {
        left -= 25;
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyS') {
        top += 25
    } else {
        console.log('why is it not working?');
    }


    coordsPlayer.style.left = left + 'px';
    coordsPlayer.style.top = top + 'px';
}

addEventListener('keydown', onMove);
```

Начнём с начала, операторы в JavaScript (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `+=` и т.д.) не могут чудом понимать величины которые вы используете. В этом можно убедиться:

```js
console.log('25px' + '25px')
console.log('25px' - '25px')
console.log('25px' * '25px')

let n = '25px'

console.log(n + '25px')
```

Поэтому для чисел к которым потом прибавляется число, обычно заводят переменные, или пропорции для объекта, чтобы уже туда их записывать. Я использовал первый вариант. Убрал также лишние консоль логи, они лишние т.к. логали контент ДО его перезаписи, то есть в логах был тот же контент, что и был указан в первых `console.log`. Также я перенёс запись стилей в самый низ, чтобы они перезаписывались в любом случае, так мы можем предотвратить лишний повтор кода. И если я написал всё правильно, то всё заработает как часы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @DimaSribnyj не за что :), Лучшим "спасибом" для меня будет галочка слева от ответа :p (Она снизу голосов)